# How to scroll a Kendo UI listview to a particular item

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have a listivew that is bound to a datasource in which the id is defined.  Is there a way to scroll directly to a particular record in the listview if the id is known?

Comment: did you ever work out a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I haven't really spent a  lot of time trying but i think it can be done with JavaScript.